# Implementing Spring i18n and L10n on my REST API

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, localization, internationalization, resourcebundle

I am developing an API which has to support multiple languages, I am using #Spring i18n and L10n for this purpose.
I am using Java configurations to define the beans as below:

==================================================================================

```
 @Bean    
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("resources/StatusMessageSource");
   // messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    System.out.println("messagesource"+messageSource);
    return messageSource;
}

 @Bean
 public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
     LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor=new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
     localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("language");
     return localeChangeInterceptor;
 }

 @Bean(name = "localeResolver")
 public LocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver(){
     SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver=new SessionLocaleResolver();
     localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en","SWEDEN"));

     return localeResolver;
 }  

 public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
     registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
 }
```

where resources/StatusMessageSource is the location I am saving my property files to which I am reading to.

I am sending the Locale as an header with the Json message and reading the locale value from the header so that I can get the corresponding property file.

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getDatedFlightsLocalTimeByArrivalStation(
    @RequestHeader(value="locale") String localStr,
    @RequestParam(required = false) String carrier,
    @RequestParam(required = false) String flightNumber,
    @RequestParam(required = false) String departureLocation,
    @RequestParam(required = false) String scheduledDepartureDate,
    @RequestParam(required = false) String arrivalLocation,
    @RequestParam(required = false) String scheduledArrivalDate) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
```

I have below parameter in the property files.

```
    ARRIVED=ARRIVED
DEPARTED=DEPARTED
DELAYED=DELAYED
SCHEDULED=SCHEDULED
CANCELLED=CANCELLED
DIVERTED=DIVERTED
```

I am missing something here, as the I am not able to read the message from the file and getting the below error while testing through REST CLIENT and passing the header as EN_SV.

```
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/sas-flight] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'ARRIVED' for locale 'en_sv'.] with root cause
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'ARRIVED' for locale 'en_sv'.
    at             org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:159)
    at com.sas.dsp.api.flight.services.FlightService.getFlightStatus(FlightService.java:76)
    at com.sas.dsp.api.flight.controller.FlightController.getDatedFlightsLocalTimeByArrivalStation(FlightController.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:534)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2381)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2370)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I was giving the path of ResourceBundles incorrectly, below is the change:

```
   @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("WEB-INF/classes/statusmessagesource");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
```